# Unable to get async/await working with Axios and array.map()

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to build a function that maps over a given array and then runs an axios call on each item. Once that is done, I want to return the mapped array for use in another function.

Here is the code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('axios');
const consola = require('consola');

function getLeagues(listItems) {
  const today = new Date();
  const season = today.getMonth() >= 6 ? today.getFullYear() : today.getFullYear() - 1; // this gets the game ready for the new season every July 1st

  // we will end up directly returning listItems.map once the issue is solved
  const selectedLeagues = listItems.map(async (item) => {
    const countryName = item.country;
    const leagueName = item.league;

    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/country/${countryName}/${season}`,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.FOOTY_API_KEY,
        },
      });

      const leagueData = response.data.api.leagues
        .filter((league) => league.name === leagueName)
        .map((data) => {
          return {
            leagueId: data.league_id,
            name: data.name,
            seasonStart: data.season_start,
            seasonEnd: data.season_end,
            country: data.country,
          };
        })
        .pop(); // we use pop() because filter() and map() return arrays and we don't want an array of 1 object, just that object

      consola.ready({
        // this displays all of the data as needed
        // this also runs after the below consola block
        message: `leagueData: ${JSON.stringify(leagueData, null, 2)}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      return leagueData;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  });

  consola.ready({
    // this displays an array with an empty object, not an array with above leagueData object
    // this also runs before the above consola block
    message: `selectedLeagues: ${JSON.stringify(selectedLeagues, null, 2)}`,
    badge: true,
  });

  return selectedLeagues;
}

module.exports = getLeagues;
```

I'm not sure why the `selectedLeagues` array is being returned before the `leagueData` object is even ready. I thought async/await held everything. Instead, in my console, I am getting:

```
selectedLeagues: [
  {}
]

leagueData: {
  "leagueId": 753,
  "name": "Liga 3",
  "seasonStart": "2019-07-19",
  "seasonEnd": "2020-05-16",
  "country": "Germany"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to wrap your `listItems.map` in a promise all function because `map` on its own isn't compatible with `async`.

```js
// Now magically you can add async to your map function...
Promise.all(listItems.map(async item => {

  // Then put your try catch here so that it only wraps around
  // the results of the function you're awaiting...
  let response
  try {
    response = await axios()
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }

  // Anything else you want to do with the response...
  return response

})).then(results => {
  // All the resolved promises returned from the map function.
  console.log(results)

})
```

When you use the `await` keyword inside an async function the rest of the code will just wait for the result of the awaited function, the try catch part is to catch any error you might get that's out of your control which is why you only try catch around the awaited function.

If you wrap too much of your code inside a try catch you won't be able to diagnose and handle the error properly.

You could put a try catch around the whole of your code if you wanted but the problem would be that the *whole* code would error out whenever you have any kind of small problem.

You can also do this with a for of loop which might look a bit cleaner...

```js
for await (let item of listItems) {
  // try catch await axios etc...
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks! And nice tip on using the for-of loop also. It does look cleaner, and easier to read. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use async together with a Promise,

```
    const arr = [1, 2, 3];
    
    const asyncRes = await Promise.all(arr.map(async (i) => {
        await sleep(10);
        return i + 1;
    }));

    console.log(asyncRes);
    // 2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in your `.map()` is async, not what's outside of it. The `.map()` kicks off but it doesn't block the `consola.ready({` at the bottom.